# DVI-D SingleLink / DVI-D DualLink

Tags: dvi, cable

I have a 2x 21in. dell 2005 FPW with a Single Link DVI-D. 
I have a EVGA GTX 760 SC with Dual Dual Link DVI-D / DVI-I.
Can I use A Dual Link DVI-D cable on both.

So in the future i dont have to buy the Dual link after buying a single link.

Comment: [Please do not add a signature to your posts](http://superuser.com/help/behavior), that is what the card in the bottom right corner is for

Comment: np didn't know, didt have card filled out at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dual link cables just have 6 extra pins that single link cables do not. The monitor side will *usually* not plug up the holes that are not used so you *should* be able to use a Dual Link cable on it (You will likely be able to use a DVI-I Dual Link cable if it's got empty slots for the analog pins (red in the below image)

Click the image below for a larger view.
[image: Color coded representation of a DVI connector]

Here is another image comparing the different types of connections with the different pin-outs. Most monitors will have a `DVI-I(Dual Link)` recepticial, even if they only connect up the `DVI-D(Single Link)` wires.

[image: Comparison of pinouts]

---

Both images taken from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) on DVI

Comment: i do appreciate your answer and help. i see i have the pins on the monitor that look like the dvi-d dual link image. i just wasn't sure because its an older monitor and the specs only say dvi-d.and the monitor back in the day came with dvi-d single link.i just never been using the dual link and never gave it any thought til i got the new vid card for it.hence my machine was my first build and its a 939 with koolance first cooler system. everything in it around it is from that era except this new vid card.9800 gtx's took a crapper. many thanks ~CHEM